# JAVA How to remove or pattern and string array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, focuslistener

I don't want to ask this easy question but i am loosing hours and I want to get it done..

```
businesAddressFields.get(TELEPHONE).addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
  @Override
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {

    String telephones[] = businesAddressFields.get(TELEPHONE).getText().split(Pattern.quote(" OR "));

    for (String telephone : telephones) {

      if (telephone.length()>0) {

        if (!telephone.matches(TELEPHONE_PATTERN)) {
          showMessage("Fehler: Telephonnummer: " + telephone + " ist nicht gültig!/nMeherer Adressen mit ' OR ' trennen.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          businesAddressFields.get(TELEPHONE).requestFocusInWindow();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
  }
});
```

I want to remove for `String (telephone:telephones)` and I need to make it only telephone because i don't have array.

I want to remove Patter "OR" because i have only one phone number.

Can somebody help me with example or with code edit for me i will be very thankful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as follows:

```
public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
    String telephone = businesAddressFields.get(TELEPHONE).getText());

    if (telephone.length()>0) {
        if (!telephone.matches(TELEPHONE_PATTERN)) {
            showMessage("Fehler: Telephonnummer: " + telephone + " ist nicht gültig!/nMeherer Adressen mit ' OR ' trennen.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            businesAddressFields.get(TELEPHONE).requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i was really dumb and noob i hope i will be smart as you one day..